# 'The drive where windows is installed is locked' Error message when trying to reset Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

On my computer (self-build) I was trying to install Ubuntu Linux with Windows 10 already my main OS. I managed to do so but after that Windows 10 couldn't boot up (it was booting for hours with no result as it usually boots for 5-10 seconds). I tried loads of fixes online and none of them worked. Here is my current position now: I have the windows 10 disc, I cant boot into Linux (I don't know why, probably one of the fixes I tried caused that)
Here is the output of everything I try:

Reset this PC (keep my files): 'The drive where Windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again.'

System Restore: 'System Restore could not find the offline boot volume. Please ensure it is currently accessible.

So my C:\ Drive is locked somehow and is preventing me from resetting of using system restore. I don't know whether this is what is preventing me from booting windows though.

Please can anyone help me at all - Thanks.

P.S. I only have one SATA HDD hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try steps proposed to [fix locked Windows drive](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/The_drive_where_Windows_is_installed_is_locked.html).

You would check partition for errors, then try to fix boot related files and if this does not help try offline repair of system files. These steps are outlined on link given.

Create a Microsoft Windows 10 DVD or USB by using [Media Creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) (if you don't have installation media).